# Int verification

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Looking at android support library i saw something i can't think why they do it:

```
 /**
 * Simple gravity to string - only supports LEFT and RIGHT for debugging output.
 *
 * @param gravity Absolute gravity value
 * @return LEFT or RIGHT as appropriate, or a hex string
 */
static String gravityToString(int gravity) {
    if ((gravity & Gravity.LEFT) == Gravity.LEFT) {
        return "LEFT";
    }
    if ((gravity & Gravity.RIGHT) == Gravity.RIGHT) {
        return "RIGHT";
    }
    return Integer.toHexString(gravity);
}
```

Could someone explain me please.

Comment: This is not android, is Java. Please refer to a Java tutorial about this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Rolled back erroneous 3rd party edit.  Java is the language, and Android is the context.

Comment: by the way, it's called bitwise operation. More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: @ChrisStratton it is not so interesting. A quick search on the net (e.g. google) gives you the answer. Downvoting and voting to close for lazyness.

Comment: Nevermind, misread the code, it's not doing what I thought.  I still think it's a completely valid and appropriate question, but it's not particularly interesting.

Answer (score 1):

& represents the bitwise [AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Example :

> 1100110 & 1100110 = 1100110

Here you pass a `gravity` as parameter. For example if you want to know that the gravity is left, you apply the mask `Gravity.LEFT` to the parameter you passed. If it is equals to the constant, then it returns that the gravity is left.

It applies the same thing for the `Gravity.RIGHT` otherwise if you're not in this both cases, it returns another value.